# Execution flow when using task.Wait in c#

Tags: c#, task

I have a sample code as below which has logic to cancel task beyond 30 mins.
Method1 calls Method2 and Method3 which takes 15 mins and 10 mins to complete respectively.I have given a buffer of 5 mins and set the timeout limit for over all execution as 30 mins.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5));
        var token = tokenSource.Token;
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            p.Method1(token);
        }, token);

        try
        {
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method1 did not finish within 1 mins :" + DateTime.Now);
        }
        finally
        {
            tokenSource.Dispose();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public bool Method1(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Method1 :" + DateTime.Now);
        Method2(token);
        return true;
    }
    public bool Method2(CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            Console.WriteLine("Inside Method2 begin :" + DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(60000); // In the actual code , this line is replaced with the line which executes for more than 1 min.To replicate it, I just made the Thread to sleep.
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Inside Method2 end :" + DateTime.Now);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in Method2");
            return false;

        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem I'm facing is, the execution order in which the methods are executed is different from what I exepected when the overall execution is taking more than 30 mins.Say suppose Method 2 execution is taking more time to finish.
**Expectation :**

> Inside Method1
>     Inside Method2
>   Exception in Method2
>   Method1 did not finish within 30 mins

**Reality :**

> Inside Method1
>   Inside Method2
>    Exception in Method2

What changes needs to be done to make the execution flow as expected. Is it even possible?

In this sample I have given only example of Method2. In reality there are 3-4 methods which performs some typical operations. Either one of them can take time to execute. So putting timeout only for Method2 doesn't solve the problem.

**EDIT2**

I have removed the old code and replaced with what was suggested in the answers to avoid any confusion. Here what I have done is made the thread is sleep for 1 min, where as the timeout is just 30 seconds. Here what is happening is, when the execution comes at Thread.Sleep, it is waiting for 60 seconds and then throwing an exception. I want it to throw exception as soon as the 30 seconds is up.

Comment: This would not compile

Comment: @TheGeneral I have edited the question now. This code is compiling.

Answer (score 0):

The code in `Method2` continues to execute even after your timeout fires - there's nothing that automatically stops it or causes it to throw an exception. What you want to do is called *cancellation*: you want the timeout to activate a signal that `Method2` can occasionally check so that it can wrap up what it is doing or throw an exception if the timeout fires.

Instead of supplying a timeout to `Wait`, create a timeout-based `CancellationTokenSource` with `new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))` and pass its token down into all of the methods running in the task. Those methods can then pass the token into any `async` methods they call and/or use the methods/properties on the token to see if the timeout has fired. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the code to implement how you suggested. I'm not sure, if it is correct as it is not working as expected. Could you please verify?

Comment: You should pass the cancellation token to the code that should be cancelled, and use one of the properties or methods on it in those methods to either figure out if cancellation has been requested, or to throw an exception in case of cancellation, whatever makes more sense in your case. In your case you have just implemented the timing part, but your methods will still continue to run.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, please refer to the edited question.Let me know if what I am doing is wrong